# Why does youtube video work fast on Chrome than firefox?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, firefox, video, youtube

As a java UI & Backend developer for past 10 years, What surprises me is the following browser behavior :

1. **Firefox** : I click on a related video (youtube website) and it takes some time to figure out the video and then buffering starts for the video.
2. **Chrome** : I click on a related video (youtube website) and it starts as if it was already buffering or buffer ready. This is surprising as there is no delay.

(note: If you have a very fast connection, you may not notice it. Slow it down by some parallel network related activity and then experiment)

My Concern is : Is Chrome browser programmed to preload some data related to youtube related videos to give a faster experience?

Google owns youtube and it makes sense for doing so. 
But doing so,seems weird. Its like unusual customization for a particular website from a sea of websites.
Anyone knows a thing or two about it?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when you install firefox you have to install flash manually, while chrome does not require that, i think it comes with it, or does not use flash at all. It might have something to do with that..

Comment: I am sure it is not related to flash but with chrome specially programmed to handle internal working of youtube as both are google products.